NULL Values For Unmatched WHERE
Say I have a table with dates and associated data for each date. I want to select every date, but only show the associated data if it matches a WHERE clause, otherwise just fill it with NULL. The goal is to have a result with a row for each date, but only cool rows have the associated data.
Table:



Date
Data




1
Not Cool


2
Cool


3
Cool


4
Not Cool



I want a query that returns:



Date
Data




1
NULL


2
Cool


3
Cool


4
NULL



Is this possible?

SELECT Date, NULL AS Data WHERE Data != 'Cool'

Do you want all other rows but Cool to be NULL or exactly those rows with Not Cool? Can any other values except those two appear? Besides the accepted answer, you could also consider to use SELECT Date, NULLIF(Data, 'Not Cool') AS Data FROM yourTable, depending on the questions I asked in this comment.

What about a date where there is no row at all? What if the same data is present multiple times?

If you just want to view your data this way, then use the following query:
SELECT Date, CASE Data WHEN 'Cool' THEN 'Cool' END AS Data
FROM yourTable;

If you want to actually update your table then use:
UPDATE yourTable
SET Data = NULL
WHERE Data <> 'Cool';


SELECT 
    Date,
    CASE 
        WHEN Data = 'Cool' THEN Data
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Data
FROM your_table;

